# Setting a Custom SEO Title Using Yoast Wordpress SEO API

Tags: php, api, plugins, wordpress

I've just installed this plugin on my site and it means that my custom titles that were previously set no longer work.  Here's the link to the brief Wordpress SEO API doc: [http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/api-docs/]

Previously, I did this:

```
$pagetitle = '' . $design['name'] . ' | Free Design from My Site';
```

I have a custom URL rewrite that takes a WP page /design/ and appends the design name to /design/design-name so now I've installed WP SEO, the page title is whatever the title of /design/ is and isn't specific.

According to the docs in the link above, I tried this:

```
function wpseo_design_detail_title($pagetitle) {
$pagetitle = $design['name'] . ' | Free Web Template from My Site';
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'wpseo_design_detail_title' );
```

That does remove the previous /design/ title but instead it just has the sites URL (i.e. the page title is blank).

I'm probably missing something really simple, right?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

why you use Yoast? just add a filter to wp_title

Comment: How do I do this within the page template though?  I've tried to add the filter to wp_title but I'm guessing the whole function needs to be run in functions.php.

Comment: you can use if home page or if page template do this. http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 3):

This is how it's done:

```
function YourFunctionName( $title ) {
 
    $title = 'Your Webpage Title';

    return $title;

}
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'YourFunctionName' );
```

But @user1502679 suggested, you can use the WordPress' `wp_title` filter (but it only works if WordPress SEO by Yoast is disabled):

```
function YourFunctionName( $title, $sep ) {

    $title = 'Your Webpage Title';

    return $title;

}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'YourFunctionName' );
```